# Group html between heading tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page with headings. I want to group the content (html) which is under the heading using javascript or any native library. How can I do that? 
Example is below

```
<div>
  <h2>Main</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2>Main2</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2>Main3</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Output should be

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Main</h2>
    <p> Content goes here</p>
    <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Main2</h2>
    <p> Content goes here</p>
    <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Main3</h2>
    <p> Content goes here</p>
    <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the required output when creating the HTML

Comment: are you asking how you would change the first HTML to the second HTML using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("h2").each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil("h2").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Main</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2>Main2</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2>Main3</h2>
  <p> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery wasn't mentioned in the question, nor was the jquery tag used - how would you do it using native DOM methods

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Ram.

Comment: It was pleasure to help you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

```html
<div>
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Main</h2>
  <p style="margin-top: 0;"> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Main2</h2>
  <p style="margin-top: 0;"> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Main3</h2>
  <p style="margin-top: 0;"> Content goes here</p>
  <img src="someimg.jpg"/>
</div>
```